# What are all the ways you can pass arguments into functions?

Tags: bash

Given function in bash, i looking for more ways to pass arguments to this function.
I knows this way: `func ${param1} ${param2} ..` .
But I have function without restrict API, and hence, in some places in my code, exists calls to this function in this way: `f ${hour}` and also in this way `f ${day}`.
And now I want to pass to this function another argument , exists way to know that in the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$#` in your function to know how many arguments it received.

Demo:

```
#!/bin/bash

tata() {
    echo "$#"
}

tata a
tata a b
tata a b c
```

Output is:

```
1
2
3
```